# Input Required HTML5

Tags: html, forms

I have this form in html5:

```
 <form method="post" action="form.php" >
    <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" value=""  required/>
    <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" value=""  required/>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="" />
 </form>
```

Sometimes i receive empty fields. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to include the `aria-required` attribute too:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php" >
        <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" value=""  required aria-required=”true” />
        <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" value=""  required aria-required=”true” />
</form>
```

Note that older browsers may not support support these attributes. On any browser that doesn't support these attributes, front-end form validation could still be achieved through javascript. You can learn more about javascript form validation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp).

Remember it is important to validate input on the server too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make yours constraints only on the client side. Anyone can send a POST request to your server without using your form easily.
It's possible with all recent browsers to edit the DOM and remove the `required` part too.

HTML5 Validations are great for helping users but it's not for security/checking.